# Create link to Bing maps with push pin at the centre

Tags: bing, bing-maps

I want to be able to include a link to Bing Maps at specific geocordinates and preferably include a pushpin at those same coordinates.

I have no problem with the centering on coordinates part of that as follows: http://www.bing.com/maps/?v=2&cp=53.02102351~-1.48398532&lvl=16&dir=0&sty=c just replacing the coordinates with those I need, but it doesn't seem possible to add a push pin to this in case I'm missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've figured it out, seems I was just searching for the wrong keywords.

From the [documentation](http://help.live.com/help.aspx?project=wl_local&market=en-us&querytype=topic&query=wl_local_proc_buildurl.htm) I was able to add a **point** to the collections editor as follows:

http://www.bing.com/maps/?v=2&cp=53.0210235~-1.48398532&lvl=16&dir=0&sty=c&sp=point.53.0210235_-1.48398532_You%20are%20here

For non-UK users who might not be able to view London Street Map, other map styles are available:

https://www.bing.com/maps/?v=2&cp=53.0210235~-1.48398532&lvl=18&dir=0&sty=o&sp=point.53.0210235_-1.48398532_You%20are%20here

Comment: that link doesen't work any more

Comment: Still ok for me, in what way doesn't it work for you?

Comment: the link above doesent work (at least on firefox and chrome), it shows only a grey background: http://i.stack.imgur.com/dUvkV.png. And the documation Link doesent work either

Comment: maybe the option `sty=c`(London Street Map)  is not available in germany?

Answer (score 1):

this will work:

http://www.bing.com/maps/?v=2&cp=53.0210235~-1.48398532&lvl=18&dir=0&sty=o&sp=point.53.0210235_-1.48398532_You%20are%20here

you have to vary the `sty=` parameter

- sty=o - birdeye perspective
- sty=c - doesent work

[see documentation here](http://alastaira.wordpress.com/2012/06/19/url-parameters-for-the-bing-maps-website/)

Comment: 7 years later....`sty=c` does work. I think you are just correct that (London Street map) must not be available in Germany.

Comment: @Fishcake it may depend on language settings: it works from Australia where EN is browser default.